# PageReference assertion error?reasons?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, pagereference

Controller:

```
 public PageReference redirectScheduleApex(){
 PageReference yourPage = new PageReference('/ui/setup/apex/batch/ScheduleBatchApexPage?ac=scheduledDeltaBatchable&retURL=/apex/mailtent');
 yourpage.setRedirect(true);
 return yourPage ;
```

In test class assert:

```
PageReference q =gbd.redirectScheduleApex();
system.assertEquals(q.getURL(),'/ui/setup/apex/batch/ScheduleBatchApexPage?ac=scheduledDeltaBatchable&retURL=/apex/mailtent');
```

when I use the same page ref as used in controller I am getting this 'failed assertion'error.Any idea about why %2Fapex%2F(as html)is needed while asserting?and how can I modify the assert to get the exact value?

Assertion Fails:

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed:

> Expected:

```
/ui/setup/apex/batch/ScheduleBatchApexPage?ac=scheduledDeltaBatchable&retURL=%2Fapex%2Fmailtent,
```

> Actual:

```
/ui/setup/apex/batch/ScheduleBatchApexPage?ac=scheduledDeltaBatchable&retURL=/apex/mailtent
```

Comment: If you try to escape them like this `\/` in assert method ?

Comment: it is because it is urlencoded url when you do q.getURL();

Comment: On another note, unrelated to your question. Your expected and actual are in the wrong places. Just as an FYI :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Salesforce URL parameters are automatically encoded so if you want to assert the url replace your assert statement with following statement where **EncodingUtil.urlEncode** method is used to encode the parameters

```
system.assertEquals(q.getURL(),
'/ui/setup/apex/batch/ScheduleBatchApexPage?ac=scheduledDeltaBatchable&retURL=' +
 EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/apex/mailtent','UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Yea,Its working fine now..